# Типы компонентов битрикс для вывод информации на сайте

Tags: php, html, css, битрикс, компоненты

Есть сайт, который я сажаю на битрикс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой компонент можно использовать для отображения 4-х вышеперечисленных отрывков (с подробным указанием свойств для хранения информации в этих отрывках)?

Comment: Либо комплексный компонент news, либо, если понадобится более тонкая настройка, news.list и news.element.
И проработайте курс https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=41

Comment: @ВикторКарев а что за компонент news.element? Гуглил - не нашел. Каково русское название компонента в редакторе?

Comment: Ошибся. news.detail правильно.

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/articles_and_news/index.php

Comment: @ВикторКарев а как задать фотографии людей, выводимых перед авторами Daniel Roberto, Marko Dugonji, Max Stoiber, Dhony Abraham, в битриксе?

Comment: @ВикторКарев  см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371706/Подключение-рисунка-в-битрикс